# python code organisation

Tags: python

As a beginning programmer (I'm rather doing scripting), I'm struggling with my growing collection of scripts and modules.

Currently, small scripts are in a general folder that is added to my pythonpath.  Specific projects get their own subfolder, but more and more I try to write the general parts of those projects as modules that can be used by other projects. But I cannot just import them unless this subfolder is also in my pythonpath.

I don't know how to organise all this.  I will be happy to get your hints and recommendations on organising (python) code.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  You pointed me to the meaning of `__init__.py`.  That's exactly what I needed: now I add `__init__.py` to every subfolder of my working folder from which I want to import.  All my code is exactly where I want it, and easily importable.  Great help, thanks!

Comment: P.S. Your scripting *is* programming. :-) Keep it up and you'll be answering questions here before you know it.

Comment: Thanks Kirk.  You're right that things can change quickly, especially with all these experts helping me out :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to read about [Packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages), specifically the part about creating a file named `__init__.py` in directories you want to import from.

I have a git repository named `MyCompany` in my home directory. There's a link from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to it. Inside `MyCompany` are `package1`, `package2`, `package3`, etc. In my code, I write `import MyCompany.package1.modulefoo`. Python looks in `site-packages` and finds `MyCompany`. Then it finds the `package1` subdirectory with an `__init__.py` file in it - yay, a package! Then it imports the `modulefoo.py` file in that directory, and I'm off and running.

Comment: You write: _There's a link from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ to it._  I'm working on windows. Would a shortcut work?

Comment: I have no idea. If not, you could probably work directly from that folder, and make a nice desktop shortcut to it so you can find it easily. The arrangement is slightly different on servers, but if you can get it sorted out on your workstation, you can figure out the server part if/when the time comes.

Comment: Depending on your windows version (starting with Windows Vista) you can also use symlinks: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/

Answer (score 2):

General-purpose custom modules should go to `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, or to `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` if they should be available to everyone.  Both paths are automatically available in your `$PYTHONPATH`.  (The former is available since Python 2.6 – see [PEP 370 – Per user site-packages directory](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These are linux paths, right?  And when i would install a new python version, the modules in `.../site-packages`are not overwritten?

Comment: Yes, these are linux paths.  Modules in these places will *not* be overwritten, as core Python has no modules in any path containing `local`.  Apart from that, these two paths are version agnostic (note the `X.Y` part in both paths).

Comment: That's not true for all Linux distros, and definitely not on FreeBSD (where Python goes into /usr/local) and some OS X package managers (where it lives in /opt). The part about site-packages being left alone is correct, though.